# Split a vector into chunks such that sum of each chunk is approximately constant

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a large data frame with more than 100 000 records where the values are sorted

For example, consider the following dummy data set

```
df <- data.frame(values = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7))
```

I want to create 3 groups of above values (in sequence only) such that the sum of each group is more or less the same

So for the above group, if I decide to divide the sorted `df` in 3 groups as follows, their sums will be

```
1. 1 + 1 + 2 +2 + 3 + 4 = 13
2. 5 + 6 = 11
3. 6 + 7 = 13
```

How can create this optimization in R? any logic?

Comment: What you need is dynamic programming. I'll try to come up with an answer but haven't use this for some time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, let's use pruning. I think other solutions are giving a good solution, but not the best one.

First, we want to minimize

[image]

where S_n is the cumulative sum of the first n elements.

```
computeD <- function(p, q, S) {
  n <- length(S)
  S.star <- S[n] / 3
  if (all(p < q)) {
    (S[p] - S.star)^2 + (S[q] - S[p] - S.star)^2 + (S[n] - S[q] - S.star)^2
  } else {
    stop("You shouldn't be here!")
  }
}
```

I think the other solutions optimize over p and q independently, which won't give a global minima (expected for some particular cases).

```
optiCut <- function(v) {
  S <- cumsum(v)
  n <- length(v)
  S_star <- S[n] / 3
  # good starting values
  p_star <- which.min((S - S_star)^2)
  q_star <- which.min((S - 2*S_star)^2)
  print(min <- computeD(p_star, q_star, S))
  
  count <- 0
  for (q in 2:(n-1)) {
    S3 <- S[n] - S[q] - S_star
    if (S3*S3 < min) {
      count <- count + 1
      D <- computeD(seq_len(q - 1), q, S)
      ind = which.min(D);
      if (D[ind] < min) {
        # Update optimal values
        p_star = ind;
        q_star = q;
        min = D[ind];
      }
    }
  }
  c(p_star, q_star, computeD(p_star, q_star, S), count)
}
```

This is as fast as the other solutions because it prunes a lot the iterations based on the condition `S3*S3 < min`. But, it gives the optimal solution, see `optiCut(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 10))`.

---

For the solution with K >= 3, I basically reimplemented trees with nested tibbles, that was fun!

```
optiCut_K <- function(v, K) {
  
  S <- cumsum(v)
  n <- length(v)
  S_star <- S[n] / K
  # good starting values
  p_vec_first <- sapply(seq_len(K - 1), function(i) which.min((S - i*S_star)^2))
  min_first <- sum((diff(c(0, S[c(p_vec_first, n)])) - S_star)^2)
  
  compute_children <- function(level, ind, val) {
    
    # leaf
    if (level == 1) {
      val <- val + (S[ind] - S_star)^2
      if (val > min_first) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        return(val)
      } 
    } 
    
    P_all <- val + (S[ind] - S[seq_len(ind - 1)] - S_star)^2
    inds <- which(P_all < min_first)
    if (length(inds) == 0) return(NULL)
    
    node <- tibble::tibble(
      level = level - 1,
      ind = inds,
      val = P_all[inds]
    )
    node$children <- purrr::pmap(node, compute_children)
    
    node <- dplyr::filter(node, !purrr::map_lgl(children, is.null))
    `if`(nrow(node) == 0, NULL, node)
  }
  
  compute_children(K, n, 0)
}
```

This gives you all the solution that are least better than the greedy one:

```
v <- sort(sample(1:1000, 1e5, replace = TRUE))
test <- optiCut_K(v, 9)
```

You need to unnest this:

```
full_unnest <- function(tbl) {
  tmp <- try(tidyr::unnest(tbl), silent = TRUE)
  `if`(identical(class(tmp), "try-error"), tbl, full_unnest(tmp))
}
print(test <- full_unnest(test))
```

And finally, to get the best solution:

```
test[which.min(test$children), ]
```

Comment: Thanks @F. Privé: I am unsure how to use the output of the function `optiCut(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 10))` outputs 3, 5, 8 , 1 what do they represent and how to use them to split this vector? Would everything be stable if I replaced the 3 in  `S_star <- S[n] / 3` with N = `some integer`.

Comment: So, the first element is the limit index for the first group, the second is for the second. The third element is just returning the minimum of the objective function and the last value is just how many times you iterate over all p (to show that this is very efficient because it discards a lot of iterations). Finally, it works only for `N = 3`.

Comment: Thank you @F. Privé, time to do some testing. How complicated would it be to make it for any N?

Comment: @missuse See my implementation for any `N` (that I call `K`).

Comment: I am really having a tough time understanding your logic of optimization

Comment: do you know any book or source where I can read more about this?

Comment: @Hardikgupta This corresponds to "Observation 8.4 (Pruning by bound)" in [this document](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/AGs/opt/Lehre/WS1314/IntegerProgramming_WS1314/ip-chapter8.pdf) (here, we minimize, not maximize but the idea is the same). For example, with `N=3`, if the last term of D_{p,q} is already greater than the minimum value with the greedy solution, then the whole sum of squares won't be the minimum for the corresponding `q` (and any `p`) so that we can prune the whole branch for this particular `q`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one approach:

```
splitter <- function(values, N){
  inds = c(0, sapply(1:N, function(i) which.min(abs(cumsum(as.numeric(values)) - sum(as.numeric(values))/N*i))))
  dif = diff(inds)
  re = rep(1:length(dif), times = dif)
  return(split(values, re))
}
```

how good is it:

```
# I calculate the mean and sd of the maximal difference of the sums in the 
#splits of 100 runs:

#split on 15 parts
set.seed(5)
z1 = as.data.frame(matrix(1:15, nrow=1))
repeat{
  values = sort(sample(1:1000, 1000000, replace = T))
  z = splitter(values, 15)
  z = lapply(z, sum)
  z = unlist(z)
  z1 = rbind(z1, z)
  if (nrow(z1)>101){
    break
    }
}

z1 = z1[-1,] 
mean(apply(z1, 1, function(x) max(x) - min(x)))
[1] 1004.158
sd(apply(z1, 1, function(x) max(x) - min(x)))
[1] 210.6653

#with less splits (4)
set.seed(5)
z1 = as.data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow=1))
repeat{
  values = sort(sample(1:1000, 1000000, replace = T))
  z = splitter(values, 4)
  z = lapply(z, sum)
  z = unlist(z)
  z1 = rbind(z1, z)
  if (nrow(z1)>101){
    break
    }
}

z1 = z1[-1,] 
mean(apply(z1, 1, function(x) max(x) - min(x)))
#632.7723
sd(apply(z1, 1, function(x) max(x) - min(x)))
#260.9864


library(microbenchmark)
1M:
values = sort(sample(1:1000, 1000000, replace = T))

microbenchmark(
  sp_27 = splitter(values, 27),
  sp_3 = splitter(values, 3),
)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
  sp_27 897.7346 934.2360 1052.0972 1078.6713 1118.6203 1329.3044   100   b
   sp_3 108.3283 116.2223  209.4777  173.0522  291.8669  409.7050   100  a
```

btw F. Privé is correct this function does not give the globally optimal split. It is greedy which is not a good characteristic for such a problem. It will give splits with sums closer to global sum / n in the initial part of the vector but behaving as so will compromise the splits in the later part of the vector.

Here is a test comparison of the three functions posted so far:

```
db = function(values, N){
  temp = floor(sum(values)/N)
  inds = c(0, which(c(0, diff(cumsum(values) %% temp)) < 0)[1:(N-1)], length(values))
  dif = diff(inds)
  re = rep(1:length(dif), times = dif)
  return(split(values, re))
} #had to change it a bit since the posted one would not work - the core 
  #which calculates the splitting positions is the same

missuse <- function(values, N){
  inds = c(0, sapply(1:N, function(i) which.min(abs(cumsum(as.numeric(values)) - sum(as.numeric(values))/N*i))))
  dif = diff(inds)
  re = rep(1:length(dif), times = dif)
  return(split(values, re))
}

prive = function(v, N){ #added dummy N argument because of the tester function
  dummy = N
  computeD <- function(p, q, S) {
    n <- length(S)
    S.star <- S[n] / 3
    if (all(p < q)) {
      (S[p] - S.star)^2 + (S[q] - S[p] - S.star)^2 + (S[n] - S[q] - S.star)^2
    } else {
      stop("You shouldn't be here!")
    }
  }
  optiCut <- function(v, N) {
    S <- cumsum(v)
    n <- length(v)
    S_star <- S[n] / 3
    # good starting values
    p_star <- which.min((S - S_star)^2)
    q_star <- which.min((S - 2*S_star)^2)
    print(min <- computeD(p_star, q_star, S))

    count <- 0
    for (q in 2:(n-1)) {
      S3 <- S[n] - S[q] - S_star
      if (S3*S3 < min) {
        count <- count + 1
        D <- computeD(seq_len(q - 1), q, S)
        ind = which.min(D);
        if (D[ind] < min) {
          # Update optimal values
          p_star = ind;
          q_star = q;
          min = D[ind];
        }
      }
    }
    c(p_star, q_star, computeD(p_star, q_star, S), count)
  }
  z3 = optiCut(v)
  inds = c(0, z3[1:2], length(v))
  dif = diff(inds)
  re = rep(1:length(dif), times = dif)
  return(split(v, re))
} #added output to be more in line with the other two
```

Function for testing:

```
tester = function(split, seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  z1 = as.data.frame(matrix(1:3, nrow=1))
  repeat{
    values = sort(sample(1:1000, 1000000, replace = T))
    z = split(values, 3)
    z = lapply(z, sum)
    z = unlist(z)
    z1 = rbind(z1, z)
    if (nrow(z1)>101){
      break
    }
  }
  m = mean(apply(z1, 1, function(x) max(x) - min(x)))
  s = sd(apply(z1, 1, function(x) max(x) - min(x)))
  return(c("mean" = m, "sd" = s))
} #tests 100 random 1M length vectors with elements drawn from 1:1000

tester(db, 5)
#mean       sd 
#779.5686 349.5717 

tester(missuse, 5)
#mean       sd 
#481.4804 216.9158 

tester(prive, 5)
#mean       sd 
#451.6765 174.6303
```

prive is the clear winner - however it takes quite a bit longer than the other 2. and can handle splitting on 3 elements only.

```
microbenchmark(
  missuse(values, 3),
  prive(values, 3),
  db(values, 3)
)
Unit: milliseconds
               expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 missuse(values, 3)  100.85978  111.1552  185.8199  120.1707  304.0303  393.4031   100  a 
   prive(values, 3) 1932.58682 1980.0515 2096.7516 2043.7133 2211.6294 2671.9357   100   b
      db(values, 3)   96.86879  104.5141  194.0085  117.6270  306.7143  500.6455   100  a
```

Comment: can you please explain how is your solution working?

Comment: Something like `inds = c(0, sapply(1:N, function(i) which.min(abs(cumsum(df$values) - sum(df$values)/N*i))))` work.

Comment: @d.b yes, exactly. Hardik gupta I hope its understandable now. d.b provided a shorter formulation in the comment above

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The runtime of Privé's answer is prohibitive for me. Your solution gave me an aswer that is very well good enough, and in dysmal runtime.

Answer (score 2):

```
N = 3
temp = floor(sum(df$values)/N)
inds = c(0, which(c(0, diff(cumsum(df$values) %% temp)) < 0)[1:(N-1)], NROW(df))
split(df$values, rep(1:N, ifelse(N == 1, NROW(df), diff(inds))))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 4

#$`2`
#[1] 5 6

#$`3`
#[1] 6 7
```

Comment: When I scaled it with my real data, it doesn't work :(

Comment: hey in this solution, for each group it picks up numbers from start. I want to pick up numbers where the last group ended. Its a sequence

Comment: Even I am trying to understand why it isn't scaling with my 1e5 dataset