# Aggregate data into bins by a certain metric

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, categories, bin

Suppose I have a data set in R below, with variables `x1` and `x2`, where values in `x1` are sorted by increasing value.

```
x1  x2 
-4  2.3
-1  2
0   1.7
3   2.3
4   3.2
7   .8
```

I'd like to bin `x1` into 3 groups, where each bin contains roughly an equal sum of the value in `x2`, (in the case below, around a sum of 4), i.e.

```
x1  x2   Bin
-4  2.3  1
-1  2    1
0   1.7  2
3   2.3  2
4   3.2  3
7   .8   3
```

Is there a quick and efficient way of doing so? Preferably using `dplyr`.

Comment: Maybe this will help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431527/split-a-vector-into-chunks-such-that-sum-of-each-chunk-is-approximately-constant

Comment: I think this is what I needed, thank you!