# chop a vector into chunks such that the sum of each chunk is close to a given value

Tags: r

Let's say we have a vector `x` like

```
x <- c(9L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 7L, 11L, 14L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 10L, 6L, 14L, 10L, 7L)
```

I want to split `x` into several chunks, such that the sum of values in each chunk should be as close as possible to a given value, e.g., 20. The last chunk stores the "residuals" so its sum should be less than 20 as well, but no need to be close to 20.

Is there any package can make this kind of partition? Otherwise, a base R method is also appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431527/split-a-vector-into-chunks-such-that-sum-of-each-chunk-is-approximately-constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following base R option, using `cumsum` within a `while` loop

```
g <- 20
out <- c()
while (length(x) > 0) {
  inds <- seq(max(which(cumsum(x) <= g)))
  out[[length(out) + 1]] <- x[inds]
  x <- x[-inds]
}
```

such that

```
> out
[[1]]
[1] 9 4 7

[[2]]
[1]  1  2 13

[[3]]
[1]  7 11

[[4]]
[1] 14  2

[[5]]
[1] 11  3  1  5

[[6]]
[1]  5 10

[[7]]
[1]  6 14

[[8]]
[1] 10  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
n <- 20
split(x, ceiling(cumsum(x) / n) * n)
```